# How to deploy Node JS application on GoDaddy VPS using WHM?

Tags: node.js, nginx, deployment, vps, whm

How to properly deploy NodeJs application with Nginx on godaddy VPS with AlmaLinux 8 and WHM,
My app is running and accessible with http://myip:3000/ but not accessible with domain.

I have cloned my repo and app is running with pm2 and accessible with http://myip:3000/

Then I have installed Nginx, and write below given code with

```
nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/defaultes
```

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I have also created symbolic link with

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/defaultes /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

Nginx is also running.
But when I visit mydomain.com i see default index.html page, And I have no idea why.
If anyone have idea what could be the issue, and how to solve it, I would really appreciate your help.
What is the problem here?

UPDATE:
I Just found that site is accessible with http://mydomain:3000/

Answer (score 0):

The configuration file you are trying to edit is most likely
/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

It might be that since you've now created a new configuration file "defaultes" it's conflicting with the mentioned path. (default)